# select special selector after $(this) selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

for example I have this code

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function () {     
    $('span').each(function () {    

        $(this).html('<div></div>') ;    
        if ( $(this).attr('id') == 'W0' ) { $( this > div ?!!! ).text('0') }
        if ( $(this).attr('id') == 'W1' ) { $( this > div ?!!! ).text('1') }
        if ( $(this).attr('id') == 'W2' ) { $( this > div ?!!! ).text('2') }

    });     
});

</script>

<span id="W0"></span>
<span id="W1"></span>
<span id="W2"></span>
```

But `$( this > div )` or `$( this  ' > div ' )` are wrong selector & doesn't work

So what do u guys suggest I should do ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use it as follow:

```
$(' > div', $(this))
```

Docs: http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/

**OR**

For direct child elements, you can use `children`:

```
$(this).children('div')
```

Docs: http://api.jquery.com/children/

**OR**

Using `find`

```
$(this).find(' > div')
```

Docs: http://api.jquery.com/find/

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/wm2140wf/)

Answer (score 6):

You can pass a [context to jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-selector-context) along with the selector

```
$(' > div ', this )
```

or use [children()](https://api.jquery.com/children/) like

```
$(this).children('div')
```

---

But your solution can be done as

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var texts = {
    W0: '0',
    W1: '1',
    W2: '2'
  }
  $('span').each(function() {
    $('<div />', {
      text: texts[this.id]
    }).appendTo(this)

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="W0"></span>
<span id="W1"></span>
<span id="W2"></span>
```