# jQuery issue need help! isuue with targeting a particular button i clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<ul>
<!-- repeating with different item_key -->
<li>
<a class="btnMinus" item_key="random-key" item_quantity="3">
<i class="fa fa-minus-square"></i></a>
<input type="number" step="1" min="0" name="cart[random-key][qty]" value="4"        title="Qty" class="input-text qty text" size="4">
<a class="btnPlus" item_key="random-key" item_quantity="5"><i class="fa fa-plus-square"></i></a>
</li>

<li>
<a class="btnMinus" item_key="random-key" item_quantity="3"><i class="fa fa-minus-square"></i></a>
<input type="number" step="1" min="0" name="cart[random-key][qty]" value="4" title="Qty" class="input-text qty text" size="4">
<a class="btnPlus" item_key="random-key" item_quantity="5"><i class="fa fa-plus-square"></i></a>
</li>

</ul>

<script>
$(document).on('click', 'a.btnPlus', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this +"a.btnPlus i.fa").removeClass('fa fa-plus-square').addClass('fa fa-spinner fa-spin');
    //loading the spin icon until value updated
    var key = $( this ).attr( "item_key" );
    var qty = $( this ).attr( "item_quantity" );
    var url = 'action_url';
    data = "cart_item_key="+key+"&cart_item_qty="+qty;
    $.post( url, data ).done(function( data ) {
      updateCart();
     });
    return false;
});
</script>
```

These code is working except if there are multiple product in the cart then on clicking on the plus or minus button, the loader spin icon appear
on plus buttons or minus buttons. problem is in targeting the particular button I clicked.

Comment: `$(this +"a.btnPlus i.fa")` here is the error, use the http://stackoverflow.com/a/30523129/2025923 to solve the problem