# How to select only direct descendants of cached jQuery context by selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, cheerio

I have a cached jQuery object...

```
$main = $('#main');
```

And I want to select all the direct children with tag name 'span'...

```
$('span', $main); // this selects all descendants, not all direct children
$(' > span', $main); // this does not work at all
```

I know I could do `$('#main > span')` which works fine, but I want to re-use the cached selector.

How can I select only direct children from cached selector?

Comment: Second with `>` should work, or use `$main.children('span')`

Comment: Related/Dup of [select special selector after $(this) selector](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30523117/select-special-selector-after-this-selector)

Comment: You can use $main.children('span') to do that, or if you think you might want to go deeper someday, you can still use direct selector, but you want to do it with $main.find('> span') to make it work.

Comment: Did you even try to goolge this?

Comment: @JᴀʏMᴇᴇ actually I am not using jQuery, I am using cheerio. The ' > span' method does not work in cheerio. I did try to google it, but there is not much info out there for cheerio. I asked here about jQuery, because I thought more people might know about that - and I did get a positive answer which was great. I hope you can forgive my transgression - but to be honest, if I was to do it all again, I wouldn't change a thing.

Comment: @BillyMoon - then tag your question appropriately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jQuery has a [children](https://api.jquery.com/children/) method:

```
$main.children('span')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the jQuery `children(selector)`-Function like `$main.children("span")` For more Inforamtion: https://api.jquery.com/children/